# How could I keep the synchronization within elasticsearch-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch-rails

I have a existing data in mysql.

I imported all records from mysql into elasticsearch with a rake task

However, I wonder know how could I keep synchronization when I delete, update, insert a record within Rails

How could Rails trigger the modification to elasticsearch? Thanks

## model

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :deadline_asap
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks  

end
```

## Rake task

For initial ES indexing

```
  task :import_all => :environment do
    Job.__elasticsearch__.create_index!
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

It should already be synchronized:
adding

```rb
include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
```

to your model should ensure that any modification will call the ElasticSearch API

To check this out, just modify a model and use your ES search, it should give you results including the frechly updated model.

Update: Here is the [Automatic Callbacks documentation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model#automatic-callbacks) in [ElasticSearch-Model gem](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model)